# Java double computing speed

Tags: java, performance, double

I have a piece of code that needs to do *many* computations based on double values, which takes too much time. Can I speed this up by dropping some decimals? if I use a formatter to parse the double, won't that do the calculus first and then shed the extra decimals, so nothing would be gained? what's the best way of doing this?

Just something to get an idea:

```
double avgRatingForPreferredItem = (double) tempAverageRating.get(matrix.get(0).getItemID1())/matrix.size(); 
   double avgRatingForRandomItem = (double) tempAverageRating.get(matrix.get(0).getItemID2())/matrix.size();

double numarator = 0;
   for (MatrixColumn matrixCol : matrix) {
     numarator += ( matrixCol.getRatingForItemID1() - avgRatingForPreferredItem ) * (matrixCol.getRatingForItemID2() - avgRatingForRandomItem);
   }

   double numitor = 0;
   double numitorStanga = 0;
   double numitorDreapta = 0;
   for (MatrixColumn matrixCol : matrix) {
     numitorStanga += (matrixCol.getRatingForItemID1() - avgRatingForPreferredItem) * (matrixCol.getRatingForItemID1() - avgRatingForPreferredItem);
     numitorDreapta += (matrixCol.getRatingForItemID2() - avgRatingForRandomItem) * (matrixCol.getRatingForItemID2() - avgRatingForRandomItem);
   }

   numitor = Math.sqrt( numitorStanga * numitorDreapta );

   double corelare = numarator/numitor;
```

Comment: How many matrixCol's go in a matrix usually?

Comment: You run on the newest JVM available to you?

Comment: Why do you think that the floating point computations are the cause of your performance problem? If I look at your code, it could as well be the class `MatrixColumn` and whatever the type of `matrix` is. You are calling those methods many times. And on today's desktop computers, these method calls are probably more expensive than floating point operations even if the their implementation is trivial.

Comment: Codo, Hotspot can inline methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe the *actual values* involved can make any difference.

It's worth at least *trying* to reduce the computations here:

```
for (MatrixColumn matrixCol : matrix) {
 numitorStanga  += (matrixCol.getRatingForItemID1() - avgRatingForPreferredItem)
                 * (matrixCol.getRatingForItemID1() - avgRatingForPreferredItem);
 numitorDreapta += (matrixCol.getRatingForItemID2() - avgRatingForRandomItem) 
                 * (matrixCol.getRatingForItemID2() - avgRatingForRandomItem);
}
```

It depends on how smart the JIT compiler is - and I'm assuming `getRatingforItemID1` and `getRatingforItemID2` are just pass-through properties - but your code at least *looks* like it's doing redundant subtractions. So:

```
for (MatrixColumn matrixCol : matrix) {
  double diff1 = matrixCol.getRatingForItemID1() - avgRatingForPreferredItem;
  double diff2 = matrixCol.getRatingForItemID2() - avgRatingForPreferredItem;
  numitorStanga += diff1 * diff1;
  numitorDreapta += diff2 * diff2;
}
```

You could *try* changing everything to `float` instead of `double` - on some architectures that may make things faster; on others it may well not.

Are you absolutely sure that it's the code you've shown which has the problem, though? It's only an O(N) algorithm - how long is it taking, and how large is the matrix?

Comment: At the moment of development, I didn't care much about performance, only readability. Computing something for any given input would take ~50 seconds, which I could live with for demo purposes. Now, I'm trying to store everything single combination in a hash instead of computing each time.

Comment: @Buffalo: Personally I find my refactored code more readable anyway - it's more obvious that it's trying to add the squares :) But as I said, are you sure that this is really the bottleneck?

Answer (score 2):

Floating-point calculations are the same speed regardless of the decimal places. This is *hardware*, so it operates on the complete value every time anyway. Also keep in mind that the number of *decimal* places is irrelevant anyway, `double` stores numbers in *binary* and just truncating decimal places could well create a same-length binary representation.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to prevent.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to make this faster is to use arrays instead of objects.  The problem with using objects is you have no idea how they are arranged in memory (often badly in my experience as the JVM doesn't optimise for this at all)

```
double avgRatingForPreferredItem = (double) tempAverageRating.get(matrix.get(0).getItemID1()) / matrix.size();
double avgRatingForRandomItem = (double) tempAverageRating.get(matrix.get(0).getItemID2()) / matrix.size();

double[] ratingForItemID1 = matrix.getRatingForItemID1();
double[] ratingForItemID2 = matrix.getRatingForItemID2();
double numarator = 0, numitorStanga = 0, numitorDreapta = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ratingForItemID1.length; i++) {
    double rating1 = ratingForItemID1[i] - avgRatingForPreferredItem;
    double rating2 = ratingForItemID2[i] - avgRatingForRandomItem;
    numarator += rating1 * rating2;
    numitorStanga += rating1 * rating1;
    numitorDreapta += rating2 * rating2;
}

double numitor = Math.sqrt(numitorStanga * numitorDreapta);
double corelare = numarator / numitor;
```

Accessing data continuously in memory can be 5x faster than random access.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to speed up your algorithm (depending on the value range used) by changing your floating point values into long values that are scaled according to the number of decimal places you need, i.e. `value * 10000` for 4 decimal places.

If you chose to do this, you will need to keep the scale in mind for division and multiplication (`numitorDreapta += (diff2 * diff2) / 10000;`) which does add some clutter to your code.

You will need to convert before and after, but if you need to do a lot of calculations using integer arithmetic instead of floating point might yield the speedup you are looking for.